# In terms of optimisation, what's the point of Ruathar?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, optimization, cleric, prestige-class

I've often seen three levels of Ruathar come up in level 20 Cleric builds. Obviously, there's no real disadvantages to taking the class (e.g. it advances spellcasting), but why would an optimiser actually take it? Considering how late it is likely to be taken, its class features seem to offer little to nothing over its three levels.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It’s something for nothing. The bar is simply low.

Advancing cleric levels gives you near-literally nothing for most choices of domains. Turn undead is rarely used for turning undead, and if you’re taking prestige classes, your cleric level for that purpose is probably too low to matter anyway. So *anything* that advances cleric spellcasting *and* does something else is better than cleric levels.

Ruathar advances cleric levels, and costs literally nothing to enter, aside from the special requirement which can (for the purposes of a 20th-level character build) be written into a backstory (and frankly is fairly likely to occur for *most* high-level characters at some point anyway, elven communities being common and great services being adventurers’ *raison d’être*). What ruathar actually does is besides the point—its 4+Int skill points alone could be enough reason to take it over cleric.

Any other alternatives are going to cost something, usually one or more feats, to qualify for, or are going to fail to advance cleric spellcasting. Anything with a cost has to be considered from a cost-benefit perspective—and if there’s something worth its costs, you’ll see that and not see ruathar, but when you just need to fill out a few more levels, ruathar’s cost of zero is very attractive. There aren’t all that many great cleric prestige classes anyway.

Comment: It's also sometimes used as filler on arcane gishes - it's easily accessible and offers full spellcasting with 3/4 BAB.